# Web Crawling with seed URLs from search engine

Tags: search, web-crawler, search-engine, google-search, information-retrieval

I need to know if it is worth to build a crawler on top of the results given by a search engine.

By that means, for a given query, grab N URLs from a search engine and input them into a crawler to find more relevant pages to the search. Is there any scientific paper/experiment claiming that doing this helps gathering more relevant pages instead of only getting URLs from the search engine?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood it right, you would rebuild the search engine, because it was its job to bring the most related/relevant results first over a search. And, although you did not mention directly your search engine, which I guess it is google, I would suggest you to use the advanced search options before trying anything else. Google provides an [API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview) for performing searches, which you can use in your system. But if this approach does not fit to you, it is possible to craw over google results, and even perform custom searches (for example filtering results by site, term or etc) but google would not be happy with this and would eventually block your calls. I suggest you give a try over its open API...

Comment: Btw, I have been using the 'google' package in Python to perform my searches. Do you know if it is possible to know when Google reformulate my query? For example, when it automatically corrected my query

Comment: If the answer is correct, please accept it. About google automatically correcting you query, you can check by querying on it directly and see if it suggest another one. This you will have to do by hand. Remember that besides google is the biggest crawler of our times, it does not encourage crawling over it...